# Access on-premise server from app service

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-network, azure-private-link

We have set up a VPN gateway and used it to connect an on-premise network with an Azure VNet. We have successfully tested a number of scenarios

- communication from VMs to on-premise DBs
- communication from on-premise computers (desktops and servers) to VMs (SSH etc.)
- communication from on-premise computers (desktops and servers) to services with Private Link endpoints (App Serivces, DBs etc.).

The use-case we are now attempting is to access an on-premise DB from an app-service. I have integrated the app-service to the routed VNet and also added a service endpoint to this VNet. I have seen infos that this should work but it is not getting though.

A second question is what is the actual source ip of the app-service when it connects to the on-premise server. Surely not the outbound IPs? These are non-exclusive public IPs. Opening these on our VPN firewall would be a risk. In this case is the solution to also give the app service in question a private link endpoint. Will it's source IP then be the private IP of the PL?

Comment: have you read this article? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/networking-features#vnet-integration and this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-integrate-with-vnet

Comment: Yes in both cases. As said I have integrated the app-service to the routed VNet. WEBSITE_VNET_ROUTE_ALL  is also set to 1 on the app service.

Comment: Ah I overlooked the bit about WEBSITE_PRIVATE_IP so that is the IP that will need to be set on the Firewall?

Comment: Not quite: "The value of WEBSITE_PRIVATE_IP is bound to change. However, it will be an IP within the address range of the integration subnet or the point-to-site address range, so you will need to allow access from the entire address range."

Answer (score 1):

Private Endpoint is only used for **incoming flows** to your Web App. Outgoing flows will not use this Private Endpoint, but you can inject outgoing flows to your network in a **different subnet** through the VNet integration feature. When you enable Private Endpoint to your Web App, the access restrictions configuration of the Web App is not evaluated. So in this case, I don't think you need to set the service endpoint `Microsoft.Web` for your web app if you have set it. Reference from [using Azure private endpoint for Azure web app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/networking/private-endpoint#conceptual-overview).

When regional VNet Integration is enabled, your app makes **outbound calls to the internet** through the outbound addresses that are listed in the app properties portal. Regional VNet Integration works by mounting virtual interfaces with addresses in the delegated subnet. If `WEBSITE_VNET_ROUTE_ALL` is set to `1`, all outbound traffic can be sent into your VNet. So the source IP address will be from the integrated subnet when app service comes to the on-premise server as the @silent's comment. Reference from [how regional VNet Integration works](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-integrate-with-vnet#regional-vnet-integration). Please note that the feature supports only one regional VNet Integration per App Service plan.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Nancy! We are actually successfully using private links (case 3 above) and service endpoints + Vnet integration + access restrictions (with WEBSITE_VNET_ROUTE_ALL) to limit traffic and access within our services and enable to talk to own VMs (etc.). How App Services work in regard to VPN integration was unclear. Unfortunately things have changed a little: the VPN GW has now been moved into another Vnet and our Vnet is peered with it. I'm trying now still unsuccessfully to access an on-premise DB from an app-service in one Vnet peered with the Vnet that holds the VPN GW.

Comment: Does the app integrate VNet and VPN GW VNet have located in the same region? If not, you are using a global VNet peering, you can not use the regional VNet Integration because there are [limitations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-integrate-with-vnet#regional-vnet-integration). You need to gateway-required VNet Integration with peering and you need to configure a few additional items to work with your app, refer to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-integrate-with-vnet#peering).

Comment: They are in the same region

Comment: In theory, it should work from app---integrated vnet ---peering---vpnGW vnet ---local network. Have you verified the route on both app integrated vnet and local network? Is there any route to from local network to the azure app vnet and vice versa? Last suggestion: you could re-set up the vpn connection after you finished your azure vnet peering.